# Different behavior when running RFT from the commandline

Tags: rft

I am trying to test an application (SAP GUI) on a virtual machine. I noticed that while my scripts performed as expected when I started them from our RFT itself, I had problems with the same part when starting the script from the commandline using Powershell on the same virtual machine.

Inspection of our logs yielded the result that certain of my methods using the `exists()` method seemed to be the culprit, as the method took 10-20 seconds to decide if an object existed, instead of a fraction of a second. There also seems a correlation between how many `exists()` are used and the extra time the methods needs (I can see duration per method): a method with one `exists()` would take 10 seconds, a method with three `exists()` would take more than 20 seconds.

My question is: what could cause this unexpected change in behavior, considering the application under test is exactly the same, the machine is exactly the same and the scripts are exactly the same. Only the method of starting the scripts is different as far as I can tell. Also relevant for this discussion: in both cases the same JVM is used.

Even a pointer in the right direction would be very much appreciated, as this problem is hard for me to get a grasp on.

Comment: Which version of RFT are you using? If I remember correctly rft < 8.5.0 isn't officially supported running on VMs

Comment: Currently, RFT 8.6.0.3 is used, but thank you for asking, as I did not even think to check that.

Answer (score 0):

The IDE or Command line should not really make any difference.
The IDE execution would be using IBM JRE  (bundled with the product) for the execution .. Are you using the same IBM JRE for execution through  commandline?

exists() should not behave differently. Is  this a consistent behavior that you see  between   IDE/CLI  execution?

Comment: Thank you Prakash, I agree it should not behave differently. It is consistent behavior and for IDE and CLI the same JRE is used, this is verified. We thought that might be the difference too.